# CSS3-Animations - infinite rotate high-res image, box-shadow pulsing glow

Tags: jquery, html, css-animations, css

**UPDATE**

Now tested some other solutions and created a fiddle. The Code in this Fiddle is correct but the animations can´t be displayed for some browsers. However now everyone can see my performance killer live. =D I hope this helps to find a better solution for creating this animation!

[*Click here*](http://jsfiddle.net/sdANk/5/)

After hours of testing alternatives I can´t increase my performance in Firefox 25 or Internet Explorer 10.(Chrome currently uses 15% of i7-CPU) In my project I have a fluid div-Container which resizes on the current display-resolution. This div-Container have rounded borders (50%) and shows up as a circle (not perfectly but this is another bug?!). In this div-Container I have a high-res image (2880px*2880px) which resizes with the height and width of the div-Container. The div-Container rotates infinite and also have a glowing pulse-effect around it.
The glowing pulse-effect (box-shadow) changes the color and width and also shows up as a circle around the fluid div-Container.

I tried to rebuild these effects with flash, jquery and GIF-Images. Flash also have performance issues with this high resolution. jQuery have low FPS and don´t looks nice. GIF-Images with this resolution gets to big.

Now heres an example:

HTML-Markup

```
<div id="disk">
   <div id="pulse"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
 function upd() {
  var h = $("body").height();
  $("#disk").height(h / 1.5);
  $("#disk").width(h / 1.5);
            }
  upd();
  window.onresize = upd;
});//]]>
</script>
```

CSS-Markup

```css
#disk {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url(hires.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto auto;
  position: absolute;
  animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {   transform: rotateZ(0);}
  100% {  transform: rotateZ(359deg); }
}
#pulse {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse 60s infinite linear;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto auto;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0%  { box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,555,0.9); } 
  5%  { box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(255, 0, 0,0.9); }
  10% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,555,0.2); } 
  15% { box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(255, 255, 127,0.9); }
  20% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,555,0.2); } 
  25% { box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(255, 255, 0,0.9); }
  30% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,555,0.2); } 
  35% { box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(103, 255, 190,0.9); }
  40% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,555,0.2); } 
  45% { box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(0, 255, 0,0.9); }
  50% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,555,0.2); } 
  55% { box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(0, 0, 255,0.9); }
  60% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,555,0.2); } 
  65% { box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(75, 0, 130,0.9); }
  70% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,555,0.2); } 
  75% { box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(143, 0, 255,0.9); }
  80% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,555,0.2); } 
  85% { box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(143, 0, 255,0.9); }
  90% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,555,0.2); } 
  95% { box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); }
 100% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,555,0.9); }
}
```

I know box-shadow animations are performance killers. But currently I can´t work out another solution for my project. The rotation of fluid div-Container uses 5% of my i7-CPU in Chrome and thats much. (without pulse-effect) Maybe I can delete some of the box-shadow keyframes and minimize the amount of this animation. But I want to get my effects to work without performance issues in original conditions.

I hope someone can help me. If needed I can create an example for you.
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

You might be the *first* person I've come across that could benefit from this but that makes me **so happy.**

Pure Javascript is way faster than jQuery.  The link below benchmarks using native properties `.outerHeight/.outerWidth` vs. jQuery `.height()/.width()` methods and shows how much native improves when the objects are cached first.

### [JS Perf Benchmark](http://jsperf.com/height4-vs-innerheight-vs-css-height)

Given the amount of processing your app is demanding, this might increase your FPS significantly.

Or my computer is just amazing and hates jQuery.  Who knows.  Happy testing :)

Comment: Can you post me the complete Javascript-Markup for setting the height and width of a div-element? (I don´t know how to do that correctly)

Comment: It's the first one on that page.  I even used the same identifier for convenience.  But if that's not clear enough:  `document.getElementById('disk').outerHeight = 50` would set the element to a height of 50px.  Same goes for `outerWidth`.  You can also use `innerHeight/innerWidth`

Comment: OK now I added the following code and gain more performance:             `function resize()
            {
                var heights = window.innerHeight;
                var height = heights /= 1.5
                document.getElementById("player-wrap").style.height = height  + "px";
    document.getElementById("player-wrap").style.width = height + "px";
            }
            resize();
            window.onresize = function() {
                resize();
            };`

Comment: Well the actual syntax looks funny but if it works for you, all the more to you.  The last part can just be `window.onresize = resize();` instead of making a function just to call the other function.  :)